# VS Code Python youtube_dl will not import

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord, youtube-dl

I have tried every tutorial online and every troubleshooting I have installed youtube_dl in everyway possible all the pip commands and using the exe NOTHING will work I have tried adding it to PATH still nothing at this rate im thinking its an impossible error

Im using visual studio code

[image]

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: Im not using that, should I? @LombardiD

Comment: If you were, that may be what was causing the issue, but in that case I don't really know. In that case, I bet its more of an VSCode issue than a python one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the selected interpreter shown in bottom left corner, run `pip show youtube_dl` in terminal, check if its location is `/selected interpreter/lib/site-packages`.

If it is, **reload window** should solve your question.

If not, please open **an integrated Terminal** and reinstall the module to current selected python environment.

[image]

Comment: Work perfectly thank you! turns out youtube_dl was in wrong version of python I was using in VS code

Comment: @billy. You're welcome and happy coding:)